# Connect with specific user [Android device] over Web socket server

Tags: php, android, websocket, embedded, ratchet

I'm trying to build a system where multiple users can establish connection to same web socket server to communicate with embedded programmed HARDWARE DEVICES.
It should be one to one communication between user and device. So far, I have worked with Ratchet and able to send and receive data over one user and and one device but my challenges is, multiple users [ Android devices ] can communicate with multiple devices over same web socket server. So, how specific user can communicate with their device over web socket server.

Comment: This looks too broad to me. You are essentially asking for a sketch of your application architecture.

Comment: Thanks ! Actually I done for one user. I am not getting logic how multiple users can connect with their respective device over same web socket server.

Comment: I am not able to build a track where each user can find their destination. In between web socket server is standing, how web socket server can connect the users with their respective devices.